# How to use selector in CSS with div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to select css class. 
But My code is not working.
Below is the code. I want to change width of button.
But the selector of CSS does'nt work. How should I use css selector in this case..

```css
 .vendor {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .vendor .vendor-btn {
      width: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="vendor">
          <button class="vendor-btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
          <input class="vendor-input" type="text" />
        </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: it should work, the usage of selectors is right

Comment: Works for me - https://jsfiddle.net/9gtdjxes/

Comment: `width` works, you should add a code that replicates the issue that you face... and note that there is a *subtle* difference of `width` and `flex-basis` for *flex items* in a *flexbox*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child elements of a row `flex` parent that don't have `flex-basis` specified will use the `width` value for `flex-basis` and the `width` property will then behave like it's ignored (as the element will no-longer have a fixed `width` value).

You can see this in the snippet in your post:

1. Click "Run code snippet"
2. Observe that the child element does have a visual width of `500px`.
3. Click the Full Page link.
4. Observe that the child element still has a visual width of `500px`.
5. Make the browser window narrower than 500px
6. Observe that the child element is now narrower than `500px`:

[image]

If you want the `flex` children to always be exactly `500px` then set `flex-shrink: 0;` and `flex-grow: 0` (so they have minimal priority to grow or shrink and will retain the `flex-basis` (via `width`) of `500px`).

Comment: width did work for me, there were may cases where i had parent container display:flex and child had width and it did work . According to this https://gedd.ski/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/ ,if there is no flex-basis then it takes width

Comment: As you can see now in OPs code snippet: width is NOT ignored on the flex child.

Comment: @Olafant Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer.